# ¿Filter con un for dentro vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo dos tablas que tienen una relación muchos a muchos, `properties` y `people`, su tabla pivote se llama `people_properties`, a la hora de convertirlos a JSON queda un objeto property con un array de people, y viceversa.
Ahora bien, necesito filtrar una dependiendo de la otra (esto en vue.js).
Despues de obtener la información, la listo en un datalist para properties y otro para people.

Datalist de people:

```
<input v-model="person" type="text" list="people" class="custom-select">
<datalist id="people">
    <option v-bind:value="person.id"
        v-for="person in filterPeople"
        :key="person.id"
    >
    {{person.name}} {{person.lastname}}
    </option>
</datalist>
```

Datalist de properties:

```
<input v-model="property" type="text" list="properties" class="custom-select">
<datalist id="properties">
    <option v-bind:value="property.id"
    v-for="property in filterProperties"
    :key="property.id"
    >
    {{property.name}}
    </option>
</datalist>
```

Sobre el datalist hay un input, lo que necesito es que cuando yo escriba un id en el input de person/people, el datalist de properties se filtre a las properties que dentro de su array de people tengan un person con el id que escribi en el input de person/people, esto realizado mediante computed property.

```
filterPeople: function () {
    return this.people.filter(person => {
        //Lógica del recorrido del array properties que posee person (objeto del array people)
    })
}
```

El problema es que dentro del filter no se como recorrer el array de forma correcta.

JSON ejemplo properties:

```
0: {id: 4, name: "1-101", property_type_id: 1, location_id: 5, area: 75,…}
    area: 75
    created_at: "2019-07-29 15:00:10"
    description: "Apartamento con 2 alcobas
    id: 4
    property_type_id: 1
    location_id: 5
    name: "1-101"
    people: [,…]
        0: {id: 222222, identification_type_id: 3, name: "Pepe", lastname: 
        "Perez", telephone: 2222,…}
        1: {id: 111111, identification_type_id: 3, name: "Bibiana", lastname: 
        "Sultanita", telephone: 1111,…}
    updated_at: "2019-07-29 15:00:10"
1: {id: 7, name: "1-102", property_type_id: 1, location_id: 5, area: 80,…}
2: {id: 8, name: "1-103", property_type_id: 1, location_id: 5, area: 80,…}
```

JSON ejemplo people:

```
0: {id: 52429253, id_tipo_identificacion: 3, name: "Bibiana", lastname: "Sultanita", telephone: 1111,…}
    lastname: "Sultanita"
    telephone: 1111
    created_at: "2019-07-30 14:13:11"
    id: 52429253
    identification_type_id: 3
    name: "Bibiana"
    properties: [{id: 4, name: "1-101", property_type_id: 1, location_id: 5, area: 75,…},…]
        0: {id: 4, name: "1-101", property_type_id: 1, location_id: 5, area: 75,…}
        1: {id: 7, name: "1-102", property_type_id: 1, location_id: 5, area: 80,…}
    updated_at: "2019-07-30 14:13:11"
1: {id: 1000697033, identification_type_id: 3, name: "Pepe", lastname: "Perez", telephone: 2222,…}
```

Comment: podrías poner tus json, para poder usarlos como contexto?

Comment: En el edit puse el ejemplo

Comment: Esos json están incompletos y en mal formato

Comment: A que te refieres?

Comment: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ayudaría mucho que des un contexto de datos adecuado para poder solucionar el problema.